# What is the expected Android push notification behavior when launching an application with a notification badge?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, maui

I have a small mobile app developed in MAUI (previously Xamarin).  We recently added support for simple push notifications which appears to be working.  Specifically, the Android version of the app can receive the push notification when it is in the foreground without problem, and if the app is in the background or not running the push notification appears in the notification center as expected.  Tapping a notification in the notification center launches the app or brings it to the foreground and the notification can be processed during the OnCreate() of the (MAUI) MainActivity.cs by looking at the Intent property.

I have noticed on Android that when the app isn't running, or is in the background, the application icon will also display a 'badge' with the count of how many notifications are in the notification center queue for the app.  This apparently can be enabled or disabled from the Notification Settings in Android.

My question is, what is the expected behavior in Android if a user taps on the app icon that is displaying a notification count badge?  My gut is that the app should launch and 'do something' like (maybe) show the most recent notification - but when I launch by tapping the icon nothing happens.  As near as I can tell, my code never receives any clue that there are notification(s) available - but tapping the notification from the notification center works like a charm.

It feels wrong to draw the user attention to an app icon with a badge saying, 'hey, look, some notifications are here!' and then, when the user taps that icon to *not* show them anything related to the notification.  So I'm trying to determine what *is* supposed to happen according to the user experience guidelines?  If normal behavior is to leave the user hanging, so be it.  But if my code is missing some event/method to process the notification in this use case, then I would like to figure out what I need to add.

Comment: "what is the expected behavior in Android if a user taps on the app icon that is displaying a notification count badge?" - that would depend entirely on what launcher the user is using, which isn't something your app has any control over (FWIW, most launchers let you long press the icon and see the notification inline there). Does you app not having any badging in app that would tell users they have a notification? If they swipe away the system notification, shouldn't they still see some difference in app?

Comment: I'm demonstrating my ignorance of Android at this point.  I didn't realize you could even _have_ different launchers.  Sigh.  Apparently my Galaxy is use Samsung's "One UI home" - which seems to use the 'long press' to 'select,remove, or uninstall'. - I just noticed Google Play showing the same kind of notification badge, but launching the Google Play app by tapping the app icon doesn't handle the notification in any way.  So I'm guessing I don't have a code problem, but it's more of a "that's just how it works" issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended for ~all default launchers - the badging of an app icon on the launcher does not usually change the behavior of what happens when the user taps the app icon. However, Android does support custom launchers that could do anything they want - including using that tap as a trigger for the notification.

Generally, you'd want to use [badging](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/guidelines#ce655353-9061-4799-8a82-52e23aafc65e) inside your app that would guide users to where they can check their notifications, even if they have dismissed the system level notification.